# resizing vmware partition

Tags: vmware-player

I have a ubuntu 9.04 vmware image but the harddrive size is too small. I want to resize the vm disk partition which requires using vmware-vdiskmanager.exe

The problem is that vmware-vdiskmanager.exe comes with vmware server. I have vmware player installed which doesn't have that and windows will not let me install vmware server if I already have vmware player installed.

Is there a stand alone download for vmware-vdiskmanager?

I'm using win XP as the host OS

Comment: What host OS?

Comment: The host OS is win XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the free [**VMWare Converter**](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to convert from your VMWare image to another bigger VMWare image.

Once the new image is created, use it with VMWare Player instead of the old one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to uninstall Player, install Server, change your disks, and then re-install Player.

Comment: I ended up going with this option